# TimescaleDB hypertable: Is there any way to aggregate data based on parameter value change and duration

Tags: postgresql, time-series, aggregation, timescaledb

I am using

- PostgreSQL 13.4
- TimescaleDB 2.4.0

I have created a hypertable called measurements

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.measurements 
(time timestamptz NOT NULL,machine text NOT NULL,alarm_msg text NULL);
```

Sample data 1:

```
| Time | Machine | alarm_msg |
| -----| ------- | ------- |
| 2021-09-23 11:59:40.0 +0000 | Device1 ||
| 2021-09-23 11:59:41.0 +0000 | Device1 |alarm1|
| 2021-09-23 11:59:42.0 +0000 | Device1 |alarm1|
| 2021-09-23 11:59:43.0 +0000 | Device1 ||
| 2021-09-23 11:59:44.0 +0000 | Device1 |alarm2|
| 2021-09-23 11:59:45.0 +0000 | Device1 |alarm2|
| 2021-09-23 11:59:46.0 +0000 | Device1 |alarm2|
| 2021-09-23 11:59:47.0 +0000 | Device1 |alarm2|
| 2021-09-23 11:59:48.0 +0000 | Device1 ||
| 2021-09-23 11:59:49.0 +0000 | Device1 ||
```

Sample data 2

```
| Time | Machine | alarm_msg |
| -----| ------- | ------- |
| 2021-09-23 11:59:50.0 +0000 | Device1 |alarm1|
| 2021-09-23 11:59:50.0 +0000 | Device2 |alarm4|
| 2021-09-23 11:59:51.0 +0000 | Device1 |alarm1|
| 2021-09-23 11:59:51.0 +0000 | Device2 |alarm4|
| 2021-09-23 11:59:52.0 +0000 | Device1 ||
| 2021-09-23 11:59:52.0 +0000 | Device2 |alarm4|
| 2021-09-23 11:59:53.0 +0000 | Device1 ||
| 2021-09-23 11:59:53.0 +0000 | Device2 |alarm4|
| 2021-09-23 11:59:54.0 +0000 | Device1 ||
| 2021-09-23 11:59:54.0 +0000 | Device2 |alarm4|
```

Here I wanted to group alarms by duration for each machine.

Expected result should be as below,

For Sample Data 1

```
| Generated On | Machine | alarm_msg | ended_on |
| -----| ------- | ------- |------- |
| 2021-09-23 11:59:41.0 +0000 | Device1 |alarm1| 2021-09-23 11:59:42.0 +0000|
| 2021-09-23 11:59:44.0 +0000 | Device1 |alarm2| 2021-09-23 11:59:47.0 +0000|
```

For Sample Data 2

```
| Generated On | Machine | alarm_msg | ended_on |
| -----| ------- | ------- |------- |
| 2021-09-23 11:59:50.0 +0000 | Device1 |alarm1|2021-09-23 11:59:51.0 +0000|
| 2021-09-23 11:59:50.0 +0000 | Device2 |alarm4|2021-09-23 11:59:54.0 +0000|
```

Notes.

- The data for all the machines is coming every second.
- Initially the
  generated on and ended_on will be same, as to track duration of
  ongoing alarm.
- Rather than writing a one time query, I want to use
  continues aggregate or triggers to continuously update (say
  alarms_history) table with aggregated data records.

For now I am using below query to get recent alarms records

```sql
WITH alarms_by_machines AS (
    SELECT 
    time,
    machine,
    trim(alarm_msg) alarm_msg,
    LEAD(alarm_msg) OVER (PARTITION BY machine ORDER BY time DESC) as previous
    FROM measurements
    WHERE 
        time >= <some recent time> AND
        time < now()
),
alarms_aggregated AS (
    SELECT 
        time as generated_on,
        machine,
        trim(alarm_msg) alarm_msg,
        EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (LAG(time) over (PARTITION BY machine ORDER BY time DESC)-time)) as duration
    FROM alarms_by_machines 
    WHERE ( previous != alarm_msg or previous is null )
    group by alarm_msg, time, machine
    order by machine, time DESC
)
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    alarms_aggregated
WHERE
    alarms_aggregated.alarm_msg != ''
ORDER BY
    alarms_aggregated.generated_on DESC LIMIT 10
```

I am still facing issues with above query, so that I want to store aggregates automatically.

So, I need something, where the different alarms would have their machine, alarm_message with generated_on and ended_on time ranges when each alarm occurred, for all the machines.

Any leads will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT:

I tried creating a trigger, which will execute after insert and will record aggregates into another table named alarms_history,

```
INSERT INTO alarms_history ( machine, message, generated_on)
SELECT NEW.machine, NEW.alarm_msg, NEW.time
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM alarms_history WHERE machine = NEW.machine and message = NEW.alarm_msg AND ended_on IS NULL);
```

At the moment, It only adds distinct machine,message into alarms_history but if a alarm comes again, it will skip(as ended_on is always null).
If I can, somehow, calculate the ended_on, and update the ended_on in alarms_history, then it might work as expected.

Any leads/ideas to achieve this?

Comment: Hey @AkshayR - we have an issue open in TImescale Toolkit to add a feature to do this I think, I'd love for you to add your use case or upvote it so we can prioritize: https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-toolkit/issues/117

Comment: Seems like you need something where the different things would have all of their time ranges when each alarm occurred, this is asking for the total time in an alarm state within a period, both things could work though they might be slightly separate, so you'd want to clarify that in the issue if you can!

Comment: Added use case on TImescale Toolkit https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-toolkit/issues/117.

Comment: Thank you! We'll take a look!